# Android sync pictures both ways

Tags: windows, macos, sync, android, pictures

I have a Galaxy s3 and I'm wondering if there is a way to sync pictures that is better than Dropbox

Right now I use Dropbox which just downloads all my pictures but it doesn't use the same folders that I have my pictures in, it just dumps them in one big Dropbox folder. Also it doesn't update the pictures so if I delete one on my phone it stays on Dropbox.

I'm looking for a better way to sync my pictures. Preferably a way that I can have the same folder setup synced as well as update deletes, renames, etc.

It doesn't have to be wireless or Internet based like Dropbox it can be a program on my computer, mac or Windows.

Answer (score 1):

For Windows, I personally prefer to use [FreeFileSync](http://sourceforge.net/projects/freefilesync/). It is open source software.

> FreeFileSync is a folder comparison and synchronization tool providing
>   highly optimized performance and usability without a needlessly
>   complex user interface.

I often use the software to do a backup of my work related data onto an external hard drive.

Answer (score 0):

For windows you can use something like [SyncToy](http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=15155). It is a Powerful sync tool offered by Microsoft.

> SyncToy 2.1 is a free application that synchronizes files and folders
>   between locations. Typical uses include sharing files, such as photos,
>   with other computers and creating backup copies of files and folders.

Using this tool you can define different types of relationships -

- **Synchronize:** New and updated files are copied both ways. Renames and deletes on either side are repeated on the other.
- **Echo:** New and updated files are copied left to right. Renames and deletes on the left are repeated on the right.
- **Contribute:** New and updated files are copied left to right. Renames on the left are repeated on the right. No deletions.

Answer (score 0):

Not *quite* what its designed to do, but google plus and its [instant upload](https://support.google.com/plus/answer/2910392?hl=en) option actually work pretty well for this - It creates 'folders' based on the day, you can keep things private, and it uploads full size images as long as you have enough space.

You can then use the G+ application on android or the webui to move around files, and [you can download the entire album](https://support.google.com/plus/answer/2710716?hl=en).

The only issue I find is with renaming - there's no obvious option to do so.